# Dataframe: looping through calling some variables while manually calling others

Tags: python

I have a dataframe `data` such that it contains multiple columns that are named:

```
 y        E4        C1  ...  season_2  season_3      ar1
```

I have list `collistful` such that it contains various combinations of **some** variables in dataframe data:

```
['E1'],
 ['C1'],
 ['C2'],
 ['C3'],
 ['C4'],
 ['G1'],
 ['E1', 'E2'],
 ['E1', 'E3'],
 ['E1', 'E4'],
 ['E1', 'C1'],
 ['E1', 'C2'],
 ['E1', 'C3'],
 ['E1', 'C4'],
 ['E1', 'G1'],
 ['E2', 'E3'],
 ['E2', 'E4'],
 ['E2', 'C1'],
 ['E2', 'C2'],
 ['E2', 'C3'],
 ['E2', 'C4'],
 ['E2', 'G1'],
```

What I would like to do is write a loop that calls/loops through the variables in `collistfull` while also manually calling certain variables that are **contained in every loop**, such that:

```
for col in collistfull: 
    datanew = data[(col),"y","season_2","ar1"]
    print(datadrop1)
```

But the code I try above returns error: `TypeError: '(['E1'], 'y', 'season_2', 'ar1')' is an invalid key`

Comment: Since it is erroring on ```'E1'``` and not ```'E4'```, it looks like you will need to handle situations when your ```collistfull``` data set has more than one variable name in it.  Maybe by iterating through them and building your ```datanew``` request differently.

Comment: @ Brian, I updatec code - it actually starts with E1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
for col in collistfull: 
    datanew = data[col + ["y","season_2","ar1"]]
    print(datanew)
```

Since each `col` is a list we can simply use `+` operator to append new names to the `col`.

Comment: Thanks.  Basic question.  Why does col work with only one bracket but ["y","season_2","ar1"] require an additional bracket.  Why not just col + "y" or how I put it above with commas?

Comment: In simple words, because a list object can't interact with non-list object. a list and a string can't talk directly, one of them needs to bow down and accept requirements of other.

Comment: if this solves your problem, do upvote and accept the answer!